# Are local IP host candidates needed for connection with STUN server?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, sdp

Are host candidates with .local needed for a connection with a STUN server? If not, how can I remove .local candidates from localDescriptions or only allow srflx candidates? I've tried removing them from the SDP but I get "The order of m-lines in answer doesn't match order in offer. Rejecting answer." I know there is iceTransportLayer: "relay", but I'm ideally looking for something similar for srflx. Thanks.

EDIT:
I have found only using the public IPs from the STUN server in the SDP only works when the devices are on different networks.
Why do the public IPs from the STUN server not work when devices are on the same network?

EDIT 2: Including only the public IP in the SDP does not work for firefox

Answer (score 0):

Seems I didn't realise that you need getUserMedia permission so it uses more than one interface.